# Symfony: Creating a new user results in overwriting of properties

Tags: symfony, entity, fosuserbundle

When someone creates a new user on our application, some of his own properties get overwritten by the new users properties. I have no clue yet, where to look for the mistake, since in the controller or entities, nothing was changed.

Here are some information: **the user entity** (we are using the FOS User Bundle)

```
class User extends BaseUser{

        /**
         * @Solr\Id
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @Solr\Field(type="string")
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
         */
        protected $firstName;

        /**
         * @Solr\Field(type="string")
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
         */
        protected $lastName;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Agency", inversedBy="useragencies", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_user_agencies",
         *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="iata8", referencedColumnName="iata8")})
         * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Agency
         **/
        private $agencies;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_user_products",
         *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
         * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Product
         **/
        private $products;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Market", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_user_markets",
         *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="market_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
         * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Market
         * @Solr\Field(type="string", getter="getId")
         **/
        private $markets;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Airline", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_user_airlines",
         *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="airline_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
         * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Airline
         * @Solr\Field(type="string", getter="getId")
         **/
        private $airlines;
...
```

The properties that get overwritten are **products** and **airlines**. There is no prePersist() or preUpdate() function for this entity!

The **create controller**

```
    class CreateController extends Controller
{

  /**
   * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER_INVITER')")
   * @Route("/user/create/{employer}", defaults={"employer": 1}
   *     , requirements={"employer": "\d+"}, name="userBundle_create")
   */
  public function createAction($employer, Request $request)
  {
      $currentUser=$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

      // get employer Object
      $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();
      $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
      ->getRepository('UserBundle:Employer');

      $employerObj = $repository->findOneByIdInContext($employer, $currentUser);

      $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

      $user = $userManager->createUser();
      $url = $this->get('router')->generate('userBundle_create', array(
            'employer' => $employerObj->getId()
        ));

      // generate form and handle
      $form = $this->createForm(CreateType::class, $user
        , array('employer' => $employerObj,
                'action' => $url,)
        );
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isValid()) {

          $tokenGenerator = $this->container->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
          $user->setConfirmationToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
          $user->setUsername($user->getEmail());
          $user->setEnabled(false);
          $user->setApprover($currentUser);
          $user->setInviter($currentUser);
          $user->addRole($user->getMainRole()->getName());

          $userManager->updateUser($user);
           if(count($user->getAgencies()) > 0){
            $userId = rtrim($user->getId(),"_user");

            $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT (a.market) FROM UserBundle\Entity\User u JOIN u.agencies a WHERE u.id = $userId");
            $marketIds = $query->getResult();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Market');

            $markets = $repository->findOneById($marketIds[0]);
            $user->addMarket($markets);
            $userManager->updateUser($user);
          }

          $this->addFlash(
              'success',
              'The user was created and an activation email was sent!'
          );

          return $this->redirectToRoute('userBundle_list');

      }

      return $this->render('UserBundle:User:create.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user'=>$user,
      ));

  }

}
```

Here are more classes that may be useful for helping to point me in the right direction.

**CreateType**

```
    class CreateType extends AbstractType
{

    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'employer' => null
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        $employer = $options['employer'];

        $builder

        ->add('firstName', 'text', array('label' => 'label.firstname',
          'translation_domain' => 'User',))

        ->add('lastName', 'text', array('label' => 'label.lastname',
          'translation_domain' => 'User',))

        ;

        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($user, $employer){
          $form = $event->getForm();

          // show iata selection if empoyer is any agency
          $employerArr = array(10, 11);
          if (in_array($employer->getId(), $employerArr)) {
            // only show iata based on user's employer
            if($user->hasRoles(array('ROLE_AGENCY_TC_ONLY',
              'ROLE_AGENCY_WAIVER_REQUEST_ONLY',
              'ROLE_AGENCY_CORE_TEAM',
              'ROLE_AGENCY',
              'ROLE_AGENCY_MANAGEMENT',
              'ROLE_AGENCY_SIGNEE','ROLE_CORPORATION_TRAVEL_MANAGER' ))){

                $form

                ->add('agencies', EntityType::class, array(
                 'class' => 'AppBundle:Agency',
                 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                 return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                 ->addOrderBy('a.id', 'ASC')
                 ->andWhere('a.id IN (:ids)')
                 ->setParameter('ids',$user->getAgencies());
                 },
                 'choice_label' => 'agencyName',
                //  'data' => $user->getAgencies(),
                 'label' => 'label.iata',
                 'empty_value' => "label.select.agency",
                 'property' => 'id',
                 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
                 'required' => true,
                 'translation_domain' => 'User',
                 'choice_translation_domain' => 'User'));
             }  else {
               // only show iata based on user's context
               $form
                     ->add('agencies', EntityType::class, array(
                        'class' => 'AppBundle:Agency',
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->addOrderBy('a.id', 'ASC')
                        ->andWhere('a.market IN (:markets)')
                        ->setParameter('markets',$user->getMarkets());
                        },
                        'choice_label' => 'agencyName',
                        'label' => 'label.iata',
                        'empty_value' => "label.select.agency",
                        'property' => 'id',
                        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
                        'required' => true,
                        'translation_domain' => 'User',
                        'choice_translation_domain' => 'User'));
                }
          // show market only if not agency user
          } else {

          // only show specific markets based on user's context

          $form->add('markets', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Market', 'property' => 'id',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
              $markets = $user->getMarkets();

              return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                ->addOrderBy('m.id', 'ASC')
                ->andWhere('m.id IN (?1)')
                ->setParameter(1,$markets);
              },
            // 'choice_value' => 'id',
            'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.markets',
            'translation_domain' => 'User',
            'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,));

          }


          // only show specific roles based on user's employer

          $form->add('mainRole', 'entity', array(
              'class' => 'UserBundle:Role',
              'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($employer){
                  $roles = $employer->getRoles();
                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                      ->orderBy('r.sort', 'ASC')
                      ->andWhere('r.id IN (?1)')
                      ->setParameter(1,$roles);
              },
              'choice_label' => 'translationKey',
              'choices_as_values' => true, 'label' => 'label.role',
              'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,
              'translation_domain' => 'User',
              'choice_translation_domain' => 'Role',));

              // only show specific airlines based on user's context

              $form->add('airlines', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Airline', 'property' => 'id',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                  $airlines = $user->getAirlines();

                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->addOrderBy('a.id', 'ASC')
                    ->andWhere('a.id IN (?1)')
                    ->setParameter(1,$airlines);
                  },
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'data' => $user->getAirlines(),
                'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.airlines',
                'translation_domain' => 'User',
                'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,));

                // only show specific products based on user's context

              $form->add('products', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Product', 'property' => 'id',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                  $products = $user->getProducts();

                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->addOrderBy('p.id', 'ASC')
                    ->andWhere('p.id IN (?1)')
                    ->setParameter(1,$products);
                  },
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'data' => $user->getProducts(),
                'choice_label' => 'translationKey', 'label' => 'label.products',
                'translation_domain' => 'User',
                'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
                'choice_translation_domain' => 'AppBundle',));
          });

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';

    }



    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'userBundle_create';
    }

}
```

Comment: What does It mean get overwritten? what is the result that you expected? What do you retrieve instead?

Comment: Looks like that some properties of `$currentUser` are overwritten by properties of `$user`. So currentUser is creating user and something goes wrong. Can you reproduce it locally? Did you try to debug it with XDebug and follow the path? Maybe some dependency was updated?

Comment: can you post the CreateType class ?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri e.g. I am assigned to product A-F and airline A-D, then I create a new user and assign him to product B and airline B. After I submit, I am suddenly assigned to product B and airline B as well..

Comment: @dlondero yes I can reproduce it on my local machine, which dependency could it be?

Comment: @VaN I posted the CreateType class (tried to cut down as much as possible so you have only the relevant data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by these to lines:

```
'data' => $user->getAirlines(),
```

and

```
'data' => $user->getProducts(),
```

To change the new user `s airlines & products collection, symfony form uses the loggedin user`s airlines & products collection **reference**.

Clone the collection when setting it as default, to remove the reference to the logged in user.

```
'data' => clone $user->getAirlines(),
```

and

```
'data' => clone $user->getProducts(),
```

Hope it helps.

***Wrong assumption***: Your error is in **CreateType** class. You use the loggedin user s properties to populate **agencies**, **airlines** and **products** fields of your form:

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
...
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
```

You should instead use the user you edit. Add in your **buildForm** function:

```
$userEdited = $builder->getData();
```

and then change:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($userEdited) {
```

in all places.

Do not forget to change also:

```
$user->getMarkets()
```

to

```
$userEdited->getMarkets()
```

in your callbacks, same for ailines & products.

Comment: Hm I don't see why that would be the problem. What I want with my logic is: The user that creates a new user is assigned to products and airlines and he should be able to assign new users to the same products and airlines he is assigned to (or less). That's why my dropdowns (the Entity Types for airlines and products) only contain the products/airlines which the creating user is assigned to. and that's what my query builder do, right?

Comment: I understand now the issue, my mistake. Updated my answer.

Comment: yes, I eventually solved my problem myself, but your answer is correct :)